# Understanding why UNION is used in this SQL injection example

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm trying to understand more about SQL injection, so I found [this lesson](https://redtiger.labs.overthewire.org/level1.php?cat=1) from Red Tiger Labs.

According to [the solution](https://aayushmalla56.medium.com/sql-injection-redtigers-hackit-4f7b9399f1b0), the `cat=1` part of the URL is vulnerable to SQL injection.

I can understand that you can append `ORDER BY X#` and keep incrementing X to establish the number of columns, which is 4.

However according to the solution, the next step is to do:

`cat=1 union select 1,2,3,4 from level1_users #`

The table name is provided, so that's ok. But I'm really having trouble understanding the purpose of the UNION. My guess is the underlying code does something like:

`SELECT * FROM level1_users where cat=1`

Presumably it would expect only 0 or 1 results. Then it prints out some number of columns onto the screen. According to the example, it prints out:

> This hackit is cool :)
> My cats are sweet.
> Miau
> 3
> 4

The first three lines were printed out without the extra SQL injection. So what's going on, and what's the significance?

I would not expect the union to do anything, I assume the numbers refer to columns?

Comment: I suppose you just didn't manage to read the solution entirely.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I am asking why the solution says doing this union is the next step. I'm not sure how that leads for 3 and 4 to be displayed on the screen, it doesn't make sense to me why it would do that or what they are signifying.

Comment: The solution you linked to explains it in detail and with practical examples. All you need is to read it whole. Particularly past that union 1,2,3 example

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've read the whole thing several times, it does not explain it. Perhaps you could paste the relevant part?

Comment: Step 3:
Now we can extract username and password from the table using column 3 and 4.
query to be passed:
`cat = 1 union select 1,2,username,password from level1_users #`

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's not an explanation, that's an instruction. My question was, why 1,2 and how does that help to convey the information?

Comment: Do you have an idea what a UNION is? If not, I would suggest to learn some SQL prior learning SQL injections. Actually, all you need to learn about **injections** is that you should never let any data directly in the query. While in order to learn how to **exploit** an existing injection, you need to learn SQL. All exploit business has nothing to do with injections but only with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to figure out what's going on here.

`cat=1 union select 1,2,3,4 from level1_users #`

The select part selects the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 as columns. You could actually use anything here, like `select 'cats', 'fish', 'bread', 42` and sometimes you have to do this as the union select must match the column types in the target table. The `level1_users` table is integers (or at least, integers work), hence selecting numbers.

I actually thought it might be selecting columns by their index, because often in sql you can do ORDER BY 1 for example to order by the first column, however that's not the case.

What tripped me up was that this particular SQL injection website dumps the entire contents of the result set to the screen, and I wasn't expecting that.  If you think about it though it is looking for a category id and therefore it's not unreasonable to expect it to list everything in that category.

By performing a union it first shows that extra rows will be printed to the screen, and because we've numbered the columns, it shows *which* columns, columns 3 and 4.

From there it's possible to simply select username and password into those columns (you have to guess the table headers in this instance because although you can normally union onto the db data it has been disabled for this exercise).

Comment: This "answer" is even more muddled than the question :)

Comment: `cat=1 union select ...` is invalid SQL to begin with and shouldn't even run

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's SQL injection, `https://redtiger.labs.overthewire.org/level1.php?cat=1 union select 1,2,3,4 from level1_users #`

Comment: Well, on Oracle or Postgres that would simply result in an error and returns nothing at all

Comment: it's a parameter that is maliciously injected so that the complete SQL string is `select * from level1_users where cat=1 UNION select 1,2,3,4 from level1_users`

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the results of our query are reflected to the page, so we must try to include the password for the user in the results query. Now, how do we do that? UNION. Union allows us to execute an additional select query and append the result to the preceding query.

We can assume that both tables (level1_users and the table which cat queries) are stored on the same SQL database.Then, we can return the password from the level1_users table by using union to get a result set which includes the password for the user.